# Examples of spaces which have explicit expression as colimits in $\mathrm{Top}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, limits-and-colimits

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ball{Ball}$**Question:**  What "well-known" spaces can be *explicitly* written down in the form $\bigcup_k \phi_k C(K_n,\mathbb{R}^m)$; where $K_n$ is a non-empty compact subset of some Euclidean space, $\bigcup_{k} \phi_k C(K_n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ is equipped with a topology which is no finer than the colimit topology, and most importantly, each $\phi_k$ is *explicitly* given.

**Note:** I know that such $\phi_k$ typically exist, but, I really only care about examples where they are known explicitly. (See Bill Johnson's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351605/l-infty-as-colimit#comment881397_351609) in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351605/l-infty-as-colimit).)

---

**Background/Motivation:**
The question is motivated by [this failed post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376293/density-of-functions-into-the-circle-glueing/376300#376300).  It is well-known that the space $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of compactly-supported functions with fine topology can be expressed as the colimit $\operatorname{colim}_k \left\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)\mathrel: \text{$f(x)=0$ if $ \|x\|>k$}\right\}\mathrel{:=} X_k$ in the category of LCS; note, we can refine the topology by instead taking the limit in $\mathrm{Top}$.

Upon identifying each $X_k$ with the subset of space $C(\overline{\Ball(x,k)})$ consisting of function vanishing on $\partial \operatorname{Ball}(x,k)$, in the obvious way by "extension by zero", we get the explicit representation of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with this topology as $\bigcup_k \iota_{k}\left[C(\overline{\Ball(x,k)})\right]$; where $\iota_k$ is the extension by zero of any function in $C(\overline{\Ball(x,k)})$.  Note, this is well defined by the continuity of any function therein.

Comment: It seems strange for the first sentence to refer to 'other' examples.  Do you mean other than $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$? If so, then it might be appropriate to mention that before the motivation. // I edited to link to *a* [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351605/l-infty-as-colimit#comment881397_351609) by @BillJohnson in the [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351605/l-infty-as-colimit) you mention, but I'm not sure it was the right one.

Comment: @LSpice  I do mean other than $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  //Also, thanks, I reformatted the intro also following your suggestion; I think it really helps streamline things.

Comment: You can't identify $X_k$ with $C(\overline{\text{Ball}(x,k)})$, use instead the space of continuous functions on the ball vanishing at the boundary.